# $P(\sum n X_{n}>m)\leq p_{m}\to 0$ for independent $X_n\sim \mathrm{Bern}(\frac{1}{n^2})$

Tags: probability-theory

For independent $X_n \sim \mathrm{Bern}(\frac{1}{n^2})$ the question is to find $p_m$, where m is natural, so that

$P\left(\sum^\infty n X_n>m\right)\leq p_m$ and $\lim_{m\to \infty}p_m=0$.

Such $p_{m}$ exist because ny the three-series theorem the sum $\sum^\infty n X_n<\infty$.

**Attempt**

1) Chebysev and Markov inequalities don't work because $E\sum^{\infty} n X_{n}=\infty$.

2) $P\left(\sum^\infty n X_n>m\right)\leq P(\{X_1=1,\ldots,X_m=1 \})=\frac{1}{m^2(m-1)^2 \cdots 1^2}$.

3) Another approach is looking at $N>m$ and using the formula from number theory

$$P\left(\sum^N n X_n>m\right)=\sum_{\ell>m} P\left(\sum^N n X_n=\ell\right)=\sum_{\ell>m} \frac{f_N(\ell)}{2^N},$$

where $f_N(\ell)$ are the number of partitions of set $\{1,\ldots,\ell\}$ of size less than $N$.

any suggestions or hints?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure I see why this is a problem: for *any* sequence $(X_n)$, independent or not, where $X_n$ is Bernoulli with parameter $q_n$ and the series $\sum\limits_nq_n$ converges, the random set $U=\{n\mid X_n=1\}$ is almost surely finite by the first Borel-Cantelli lemma. Furthermore, for every sequence $(x_n)$, the series $\sum\limits_nx_nX_n$ converges almost surely on the event that $U$ is finite, hence its sum $S=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty x_nX_n$ is such that $P(S>s)\to0$ when $s\to+\infty$. To sum up, your case is when $q_n=\frac1{n^2}$ and $x_n=n$, and the value of each $p_m$ is irrelevant.

Comment: We already know that $P(S>s)\to 0$ simply because the sum is finite (from your argument or just the three series theorem as I mentioned above). The question is to bound how fast it goes to zero; to get a rate of convergence. The $p_{m}$ are meant to be that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$P(S\geq m)=1-P(\sum^{m-1}X_{k}k<m)\prod_{k\geq m}(1-\frac{1}{k^{2}})$

$=1-(1-P(\sum^{m-1}X_{k}k\geq m))\prod_{k\geq m}(1-\frac{1}{k^{2}})$

$=1-\prod_{k\geq m}(1-\frac{1}{k^{2}})+P(\sum^{m-1}X_{k}k\geq m))\prod_{k\geq m}(1-\frac{1}{k^{2}}) $

$\leq 1-\prod_{k\geq m}(1-\frac{1}{k^{2}})+(\frac{m-1}{m^{2}}+\frac{2\sum_{1\leq j< l\leq m-1}\frac{1}{lj}}{m^{2}})\prod_{k\geq m}(1-\frac{1}{k^{2}})=:p_{m} $

$\sim 1-\prod_{k\geq m}(1-\frac{1}{k^{2}})+(\frac{1}{m}+\frac{2log(m)^{2}}{m^{2}})\prod_{k\geq m}(1-\frac{1}{k^{2}}) $

$\to 1-1+(0+0)\cdot 1=0$